# How to create textviews one below one programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

**How to create textviews one below one programmatically?**

I want to create textviews programmatically one below one textview in linearlayout. I have given image link same as that image (with same alignments as shown in image) I want to create.

[image: output I want]

Comment: What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: @MikeM. see second image with **Result I want to get**  i want this output

Comment: Then change `rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);` to output the `String` you want. Like I said, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @MikeM. wait let me explain u .... as i told u to see second image right ..    in this image i get textview vertically only left side i want to add one textview left and one right side . side by side  now got it?

Comment: No, not at all. That's why you need to edit your question to clarify _exactly_ what you're trying to do. Your hand-drawn diagram isn't really telling us anything, other than you want different text.

Comment: Okay fine i change que and code also have look and ans  @MikeM.

Comment: @MikeM. now see my updated question

Comment: @sufiyan I suggest creating a TextView for each caractere of word. And for each one caractere you will connect with "android:layout_below:"@id" " with another TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Use different centered TextView objects inside a LinearLayout of your XML.